# Extend by/for - Correct Usage

Tags: prepositions, american-english

Do the below sentences convey the same meaning?

1. If this petition is approved, you can extend your legal status by (additional/up to) 2 years.
2. If this petition is approved, you can extend your legal status for another 2 years.
3. If this petition is approved, you can extend your legal status another 2 years.

Comment: The standard English formulation for references to following material is “sentences below”, not “below sentences”. This may seem academic, but such references tend only to occur in more academic texts.

Comment: Another point is to write numbers up to at least ten as words. The limit varies, but the point is that that is what people say, whereas numerals appear mathematical.

Comment: Thanks a lot!@David

Comment: Regarding your first comment, are you saying ‘below sentences’ tend only to occur in more academic texts?

Comment: I'm saying "sentences/diagram/illustration below " is the only version I have ever encountered in professional printed material of any type (British or American) in an academic career as a scientist and a British native-speaker who reads widely in other areas. I have only encountered "below sentence" etc on the internet, and have presumed that it is a mistake (quite common) of non-native speakers or native speakers who have never published. Google ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sentence+below%2Cbelow+sentence&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Answer (score 1):

The structures

Extend + NP + by + temporal measure phrase

> - *You can now extend this by a further three months* [[Wellcome.org](https://wellcome.org/grant-funding/guidance/coronavirus-covid-19-information-grant-applicants-and-grantholders)]
> - ... *extend this by six months in some circumstances*. [[UK Parliament Publications](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/jt201314/jtselect/jtpcbs/27/27ix_we_j13.htm)]
> - *Once we have the information we need, we will generally respond within eight* *weeks (although we can extend this by a further six weeks*
>   *in* ... [[Information Commissioner's
>   Office](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/uk-gdpr-guidance-and-resources/accountability-and-governance/guide-to-accountability-and-governance/accountability-and-governance/data-protection-impact-assessments/)]

and Extend + NP + for + temporal measure phrase

> - *For example, if your Visitor Visa was granted for 3 months, you will be able to* *extend this for a further 3 months*. [[Reiss Edwards
>   Solicitors](https://immigrationlawyers-london.com/blog/uk-visitor-visa-extension.php)]
> - *A doctor can extend this for up to 12 hours if they are unable to complete* *assessment* [[NHS; Northumberland, Tyne &
>   Wear](https://www.cntw.nhs.uk/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/NNTGS136-LP-1.pdf)]
> - *We may extend this for a further two months if your request is large or complex*. [[Warwickshire County
>   Council](https://www.warwickshire.gov.uk/council-democracy-councillors/access-information/4)]

and Extend + NP + no preposition + temporal measure phrase (so preposition deletion)

> - *The FA here have proposed to extend this another year to 12 year olds*
>   *too*. [[RefChat](https://refchat.co.uk/threads/at-what-age-of-player-do-you-apply-the-law.8345/)]
> - *And now we have a chance to extend this another two months.* [[The White
>   House](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefing-room/press-briefings/2022/08/02/press-briefing-by-press-secretary-karine-jean-pierre-and-nsc-coordinator-for-strategic-communications-john-kirby-august-2-2022/)]

can all readily be found on the internet, as the examples suggest. I'd say that the third variant (with preposition deletion) is rarer and especially without padding such as 'a further' / 'another'. It is more common in the US than the UK, and less formal than the other variants.

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much. @Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Would ‘additional’ also work as a padding? If so, do I put ‘an’ before the word?

Comment: Yes, certainly; and yes, you must. Another/ a further / an additional / an extra ....